# Add new container in Group product View Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I want to add new container only for group products in Frontend.

[image]

Above Screenshot is group product's view page of my magento frontend.

In above Screenshot,I want to add that container Div below reviews container.

Comment: Do you need a tab next to reviews or another div entirely after reviews?

Comment: Did you try my code? If you do not know how to implement it I'll make it more detailed.

Comment: I need another div entirely after reviews Anime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you have to follow this procedure.

**1. Override `Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml`**

First **create a module** inside which create a **layout** file `/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">  
       <action method="setTemplate"> 
           <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_YourModule::details.phtml</argument>
       </action>  
   </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**2. Create your `details.phtml`** at location `/app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/details.phtml`

**Make sure you copy whole code from core file** and make necessary changes like adding your own div.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <div class="product info detailed">
        <?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
        <div class="product data items" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name):?>
                <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
                ?>
                <div class="data item title"
                     aria-labeledby="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title"
                     data-role="collapsible" id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>">
                    <a class="data switch"
                       tabindex="-1"
                       data-toggle="switch"
                       href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"
                       id="tab-label-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias;?>-title">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="data item content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>" data-role="content">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $html; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--now on goes my logic to add a div for grouped product. -->
<?php if($block->getProduct()->getData('type_id')=='grouped'): ?>
    <div id='custom_block'>
        <h2>This is my added div.</h2>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**3. Output**
You can see that my div is seen only for grouped product.
[image]

Comment: Thank u so much Anime. It was very useful to me. But can i do this inside "module-grouped-product" module instead of create new module.?

Comment: Hello nagaraj, you must not write code in core folders, it is bad practice , make your own module. It is an easy task.

Comment: @PurushotamSangroula, awesome. is there have any options to add a custom block next to add to cart button?

Comment: @senthil Yes, there is, thank you for your appreciation