# Magento 2 : Add Block After Add To Cart Button

Tags: magento-2.1, product, addtocart

I have to add block and call custom phtml file after "Add to Cart" button on product details page.

I have added below code in catalog_product_view.xml file in extension.

It is working but displaying before Qty input box

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

But it's not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry"name="product.info.enquiry" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <!-- for config products -->
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: why should I include two reference block(product.info.addtocart, product.info.addtocart.additional)? what is the exact meaning of this

Answer (score 6):

Use below step to add block/template below the Add to Cart button

Create file in your module/theme catalog_product_view.xml

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block
                class="[Compney]\[Module]\Block\Catalog\Product\Block"
                name="product.info.anyname"
                template="[Compney]_[Module]::catalog/product/phtmlfile.phtml"
                after="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have to add by extension file not by theme file

Comment: I have also used this code in extension but not working.

Answer (score 2):

you are using same block name in both the blocks that is why its not working.

Try below code

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\XYZ" name="block.name.one" as="makeoffer.button" template="Namespace_Module::template.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
</referenceContainer>
<!-- for config products -->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\XYZ" name="block.name.two" as="makeoffer.button.additional" template="Namespace_Module::template.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code or create a new file in

`app/code/Vendor/CustomBlock/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Then you can add below content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.extrahint">
            <block
                class="Vendor\CustomBlock\Block\Catalog\Product\Presell"
                name="product.block_name"
                template="Vendor_CustomBlock::catalog/product/presellInfo.phtml"
                before="product.info.social"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

   <body>   
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry" after="product.info.addtocart" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
        </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this question.I am also needed this kind of solution,It was helped to me.

[Add new container in Group product View Page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/add-new-container-in-group-product-view-page-in-magento-2)

It will definitely help you.

This answer is for grouped product.If you want to simple product page,remove the if condition `if($block->getProduct()->getData('type_id')=='grouped'):` from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i fixed it by changing block name

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry"name="product.info.enquiry" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <!-- for config products -->
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry-additional" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

change the name of second block so that it donot match with simple products block name