# Add text under AddToCart Button in Product Description Page Frontend - Magento2.3.5-p2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, addtocart, catalog, phtml

I tried so many ways to add text under addtocart button in PDP page, but nothing works. My block  and phtml not getting called.

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="MyVendor\MyProject\Block\Product\Message" name="product.infor.message" after="product.info.addtocart"
template="MyVendor_MyProject::product/message.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

I tried with the following blocks and its not working.

```
name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"
name="product.info.addtocart.additional"
```

i think just because im referring child block or container, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

just tried this one below and it shows up the template right below the add to cart button.

`product.info.form.content` is the right container to refer and you can add your block `after` `product.info.addtocart` block.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="below.addtocart" template="Vendor_MyModule::product/view/below-addtocart.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart">
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>   
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry"name="product.info.enquiry" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <!-- for config products -->
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <block class="Package_Name\Module_Name\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Enquiry" name="product.info.enquiry-additional" template="Package_Name_Module_Name::catalog/product/view/enquiry.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305278/94299